# How to prevent "animated" bokeh plot from stuttering

Tags: animation, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to create a kind of dashboard for monitoring ECG data and relevant features. When "animating" the ECG by constantly updating two `ColumnDataSource`s, very soon the plot starts stuttering and growing slow. At the moment, I'm running this in a notebook, but it's the same with a bokeh server.

The ECG itself shows about the latest second, some 400 data points in a line. Left on its own, this runs almost smooth, but this is not really helpful, dashboard-wise. Another plot shows the heart rate variability, maybe a dozen circles but derived from the last minute of data, thus the two sources.

It seems that the more is gathered in the data sources and the faster the updates happen, the slower the plotting becomes. The `rollover` parameter of `ColumnDataSource.stream()` cuts the overall length of what is collected but ultimately does not prevent the stuttering.

There is probably some rookie mistake in my code, as I feel bokeh should be well-equipped for visualizing such an amount of data. So, here is what I do for plotting:

```py
dashboard_source = ColumnDataSource(record[:1]) # initialize with first row
ecg_source = ColumnDataSource(record[:1]) # initialize with first row

# some options
time_window = 12 # seconds to keep in view
ecg_length = 1 # seconds to keep in view in ECG plot
update_rate = 1000 / sampling_rate # number of milliseconds between each plot update

# update function in which source data is fed from record dataframe
current_record_pos = 1
def update_dashboard_source():
    global current_record_pos
    new_row = record.iloc[current_record_pos]
    dashboard_source.stream(new_row, rollover = sampling_rate * time_window)
    ecg_source.stream(new_row, rollover = sampling_rate * ecg_length)
    current_record_pos += 1

def ecg_dashboard(doc):

    # dashboard element: ECG plot/s ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- -------

    ecg_plot = figure(width=800, height=400, title='ECG', x_axis_label='time in ms', y_range=(-1, 1.5))

    # plot ECG channels
    for record_channel, color in zip(record_channels, ['green', 'blue']):
        ecg_plot.line(source=ecg_source, x='time_ms', y=record_channel, alpha=.3, legend=record_channel+' ', color=color)

    # dashboard element: heart rate variability ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- -------

    hrv_plot = figure(width=400, height=400, title='heart rate variability', x_axis_label="r'r''", y_axis_label="r''r'''")
    hrv_plot.circle(source=dashboard_source, x='r_diff_1', y='r_diff_2', size=10, alpha=.23)

    # gather everything in a dashboard element and add it to the document
    ecg_row = row(ecg_plot)
    feature_row = row(hrv_plot)
    dashboard = column(ecg_row, feature_row)
    doc.add_root(dashboard)
    doc.add_periodic_callback(update_dashboard_source, update_rate)

show(ecg_dashboard)
```

I did not find bokeh's user guide very helpful regarding updated plotting. Is there maybe a collection of best practices somewhere?

Comment: what is your sampling rate? Is it necessary updating the ecg_plot or other data more then twice a second?

Comment: The `sampling_rate` is mostly 360 at the moment, but could also be around 250 or 500. The goal is to provide the ECG in "true" speed, so I need an according update rate. Dropping, say, every third or second data point could possibly be done without losing much visible information, but I'd prefer to include all the data.

Comment: Given sampling_rate of 250 the update_rate value passed to add_periodic_callback() is **4ms !!!** So you are trying to update multiple plots **250 times per second !** I don't believe this is **not** what Bokeh or any browser in general can do with respect to required performance in this case.

Comment: Ah, so bokeh might not be what I'm looking for, anyway, due to its browser-centric design? Tinkering with the update rate by omitting data or adding it in larger packets already helps, but using a browser for viewing is not really a requirement for me. Could another plotting library be a better fit?

Comment: I think this is rather browser then Bokeh bottleneck (compared to DDOS attack), so I am not sure about alternatives. I would simply try to limit the callback period to let's say 50-100ms. You will still have 10-20 points per second.

Comment: Yup, thanks - less updates (with larger packets) work fine, and if you keep it still under or around 100 ms you don't introduce any gaps in the update, either. You could add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluding the conversation in comments: Each time a single point is added to the plot the entire canvas area in the browser is being re-drawn. This is how browsers work. Having a `sampling_rate` of 250 results in 250 plot updates per second that is one update per 4ms. This will make the browser running slower and slower as the number of points to be rendered (re-redrawn) every 4ms will increase.

I would advice to increase the update period from 4ms to about 100ms (possibly with larger data packets)